# Unable to retrieve metadata for MyApp.Models.MyClass while generating view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

I am developing an application with the help of this link:

http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/9a5fe277-6e7e-43e5-8408-a28ff5be7801.aspx

While generating view to the BasicDetails, getting this error:

```
Unable to retrieve metadata for WebApplication.Models.BasicInfo
```

Here is my Connection String:

```
<add name="CompanyEntity" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Employee.csdl|res://*/Models.Employee.ssdl|res://*/Models.Employee.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=myservername;initial catalog=Company;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

I am creating this application in MVC5.

My BasicInfo class:

```
public class BasicInfo
{
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    public string CompName { get; set; }
}
```

My BasicInfo in EmployeeController class:

```
public ActionResult BasicInfo(BasicInfo Details, string BtnPrevious, string BtnNext)
    {
        if (BtnNext != null)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Employee ObjEmp = GetEmployee();
                ObjEmp.EmployeeName = Details.EmpName;
                ObjEmp.CompanyName = Details.CompName;
                return View("AddressInfo");
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your action result is doing but the error means that there is something is wrong with a connection string.